# jQuery add active tab class to the Body tag

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass

On the website im building, each tab has a class on its li of either tab1, tab2, tab3 etc

What I want to do is first check to see if a tab has a class of "cur" then if it does, check the rest of the li to see if it has another class of either "tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4" or "tab5" then add that "tab" class to the body tag

to get get something like this

```
<body class="tab2">


<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li class="current1 tab1">First Tab</li>
    <li class="current1 cur sub tab2">Second Tab</li>
    <li class="current1 sub tab3">Third Tab</li>    
    <li class="current1 sub tab4">Fouth Tab</li>    
    <li class="current1 sub tab5">Fifth Tab</li>    
</ul></div>
```

i've tried something like the jQuery below but it always adds an additional class of tab5 to the body as well

```
 if ( $('.navigation ul li.tab1').hasClass('cur') ) {
        $('body').addClass('tab1'); 
     } else if ( $('.navigation ul li.tab2').hasClass('cur') ) {
        $('body').addClass('tab2'); 
    } else if ( $('.navigation ul li.tab3').hasClass('cur') ) {
        $('body').addClass('tab3'); 
    } else if ( $('.navigation ul li.tab4').hasClass('cur') ) {
        $('body').addClass('tab4'); 
    } else ( $('.navigation ul li.tab5').hasClass('cur') ); {
        $('body').addClass('tab5');
    }
```

I know there is a much cleaner way of doing it but can't seem to work it out

I wish I could just add the class manually, but i dont have access to the HTML so have to generate it with javaScript

Any help much appreicated

Thanks

Comment: If I may, I wrote a blog on jQueryUI Tabs and how to manipulate them far beyond what is mentioned in their own documentation. [Take a look at it, it may help you to reach your end goal much easier](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/08/jqueryjqueryui-help-tabs-get-currently.html)

Comment: On another note, if you use jQueryUI Tabs, theere is an `activate` event you can use to set your class on you body much easier. Something like `.tabs({ action: function(e, ui) { $("body").removeClass(ui.oldTab.attr("class")).addClass(ui.newTab.attr("class")); } })`

Comment: Updated myy answer to work and including fiddle in a sec

Answer (score 1):

Following only the basics you have provided (unsure if your using a tabs library from somewhere like jQueryUI), you can very easily simplify what you're doing without all the ifs.

See Below:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/tab[0-9]/),
    tabClass = "" + $(".cur").attr("class").match(patt);
$('body').removeClass("tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5")
    .addClass("" + tabClass); // the "" + is required
```

As One Line:

```
$('body').removeClass("tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5").addClass("" + $(".cur").attr("class").match(/tab[0-9]/));
```

## jsFiddle

> Breakdown of the 1-liner

- [$('body')](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) jQuery Selector - This one grabs the `body` element
- [.removeClass("tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4 tab5")](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) removes possible classes from element, no error if class does not exist on element, so no worries
- [.addClass(](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) this begins adding the class you want to add to your body element
- "" + [$(".cur")](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) The " here ensure a proper string return of a regex match, and of course your basic jQuery Selector again, in this case grabbing elements with the class `cur`
- [.attr("class")](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) This seeks to get all classes on element containing class `cur`

  - in newer jQuery versions, you might consider changing this to [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [.match(/tab[0-9]/)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)) Finally, the old JS match method used with regex to pull out only the class name begining with `tab` and ending with an integer 0 through 9 and of course the closing `)` for the call of [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on element `body`

Comment: This is just what i was looking for, it's simple and works. Good day to you sir

Comment: Not a problem. There are some "ol' school" train of thought programmers who feel you have to break everything down and seperate everything out. Some of those even prefer libraries like Dojo and Prototype. At the end of the day, jQuery reminds us what makes JavaScript different, "keep it simple".

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
$('.navigation ul li.cur');
```

you will get back an array of all elements that match the selector.  You can then use the element ids ala:

```
var elems=$('.navigation ul li.cur');
$('body').removeClass()
elems.each(function(){
    $('body').addClass($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    // set the attribute of tab that was clicked as active
    $(this).attr('class', 'active');                
});
```

Find the jsfiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/P5Kzr/